# How to change selected value of aria listbox using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, listbox, wai-aria

## I'm trying to change the listbox option[shown in image below] to JPY ¥ using javascript

however there are a lot of issues that come here and I just don't know how to go about it...

[image]

**A thing to notice is, on changing to JPY the right hand side gift-total value also changes from 0.00 to 0**

this is the external showcase of the listbox [image]

and these are the listbox options(the id changes every refresh to the webpage)
[image]

If you open the listbox dropdown and try to pick an option
`aria-activedescendant` and `aria-owns` attributes dynamically get added into the div listbox html element

which are using the id of the listbox options
[image]

[image]

^Source for definition images:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/listbox_role

### What I have tried:

Now I have tried changing innerHTML of the element
however apparently that only changed the visual aspect, as currency never changed to japanese yen on the next page that would you know charge you some amount

any way on how I should go about to directly change its value using javascript without resorting to clicks and all

Spent a few hours on stackoverflow and google but only one similar question which no one has answered unfortunately

#### TLDR;

most likely tldr; change selected value of aria listbox using javascript
except this thing doesn't use `aria-selected` which is causing me major pain to understand how to make an autofill for it.

##### Link to try for yourself:-

https://examplegroup.chatango.com

=> You would have to sign up/register to view the svg (triple bars/rectangles) at bottom right corner.

=> Clicking on "Extended Features" and then clicking on "Purchase an original account" will result in reaching my starting line from which you can replicate and assist further in figuring a solution to it.

Comment: Is this your codebase? If so you can assign an ID to whatever element and make changes on value.

Comment: @GetSet it isn't my codebase, Its an external website on which I am trying to have the currency autofilled to JPY using javascript so that I can click on next without having to change it everytime. I've also attached the link with instructions at the very bottom, you can check.

Comment: You wont be able to change an external's site defaults because the rendering of the external site's page happens independently of whatever changes you need to apply to it. Perhaps you could instead tell us *wHy* you want to do what it is you want to do for further insights that could be of help to you.

Comment: It is sort of how an autofiller extension works, I am able to autofill the username for example (in the first image) using Javascript to click on add without having for myself to type the name out , the same is also possible for dropdown html inputs just don't know how I would go about it on an aria listbox

Comment: Find something "unique" about the element. Maybe it has a class name the others do not. Maybe it's nested further in "class names" the others do not.

Comment: @GetSet I'd highly recommend you to try it as I've spent an entire night on it with the only unique thing about the element being its text attribute, I could use it to get the dynamically changing id of the element, however that still doesn't answer how I would use javascript and the id of the option element I want to pick from the listbox to achieve an autoselect/autofill of the option on the listbox

Comment: I disagree. From the code you've shown, the element is nested in structure. The structure itself can qualify the target element's "uniqueness".

Comment: @GetSet yes, however we both end up on the same path ...
Now I have the "id" of the listbox option element ...
It still won't answer what do I do with this "id", how do I make this "id" the autofilled selection option of the listbox

Comment: It's an interesting problem. Perhaps it's not *really* a "listbox" but a UI rendering of one via the scripts on that page? It would be necessary to find where the value is really stored on the client-side to then trigger those events on such change. And here is when I personally get into the how would this even be possible to trigger such events, being that this is not your codebase? But you seem to know what you are doing.

Comment: @GetSet I did a lot of research so I can confirm, it is an Aria Listbox except the website seems quite old more than 10 years old so they're using divs for the listbox and the options inside which might make it seem like you can't find any <li>, the normal method to auto fill an aria listbox would be to capture its list elements, set the `aria-dropdown` of the listbox to true, and change the `aria-selected` value of the currently selected option to false and changing your desired option's aria-selected attribute to true... the issue being they're not using aria-selected attribute anywhere...